# Win10 won't boot up, no restore option working

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot

On a Win10 system that won't boot up, the Win10 iso does not actually show the reset option like it should - the startup repair or uninstall upgrades won't do anything naturally either. Many people note that feature doesn't work - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/no-option-for-reset-my-pc/283cd126-8970-44c9-a183-0ed3f8ac72c8

And chkdisk showed no disk errors. sfc or dism command does not work, as usual.

So could I look at the HDD, and the USB Windows iso drive contents while running Linux bootable drive, and find and copy files that someone/something moved or corrupted? [This](https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/use-these-command-prompt-commands-to-fix-or-repair-corrupt-files/) suggests that may be possible. Is there any tool to do this automatically?

Comment: Boot with a bootable USB key and from there see if the drive responds properly. It appears to have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should backup the files on that drive and do a clean installation of windows
by bootable USB